# User not defined issue for specific controller while passing data to view page in express nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller

I am using express js as framework and ejs for view engine now for specific controller while passing data from controller to view it shows user not define with in view/partial/header.ejs which is working fine for other controller.

[image: passing view from controller to view engine]

Controller code:

```
 app.get('/add_home_content', function(req, res) {
    User.findById(req.user, function(err, doc) {
            if (doc.local.role == 'admin') {

       var catId = '59f9be1aa40c152bc990f98f';
       var contentid2 = '59faef18ce5da81b59c70a34';
        var homeimgid = "59fc0e3e20942a15d7633cfd";
        var contentplanid = "5a002bf79a62fc0bf2f14bbe";
        content.findById(catId, function(err, content) {
//content.find({} ,{ "type": "homepage" }, function (err, content) {
            //res.send(req.user.local);


           trainercontent.findById(contentid2, function(err, trainercontent) {

                homeimage.findById(homeimgid, function(err, homeimage) {
                    trainerinfo.find({}).exec(function(err, trainerinf) {
                        traininginfo.find({}).exec(function(err, traininginf) {
                            subscplancontent.findById(contentplanid, function(err, plancontent) {
                                banner.find({}).exec(function(err, bannerinf) {
                                    // notification.find({}).exec(function(err, notifications) {
//res.send(content);
                                    //trainercontent.find({}).exec(function(err, trainercontent) {
                                    // res.send(notifications);
                                    res.render('admin/content/addcontent.ejs', {
                                        editContent: content,
                                        editcontent2: trainercontent,
                                        editcontent3: homeimage,
                                        trainerinfo: trainerinf,
                                        traininginfo: traininginf,
                                        plancontents: plancontent,
                                        bannerinfo: bannerinf,
                                        message: false,
                                        user: req.user.local
                                    });

                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
    });
    });
```

View page code(view engine ejs code) Showing user undefined error:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        /********signUp form validation *********/
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#planAdd').submit(function(e) {

                var valid = $("#planAdd").valid();
                if (valid) {} else {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
          $('#planAdd').validate({
                rules: {
                    'plan_name': 'required',
                    'price': 'required',
                    'currency': 'required',
                    'plan_duration': 'required'
                 },
                messages: {
                    plan_name: {
                        required: "Plan can't be blank"
                    },
                    price: {
                        required: "Price can't be blank"
                    },
                    currency: {
                        required: "Currency can't be blank",
                      }, 
                    plan_duration: {
                        required: "Plan Duration can't be blank"
                    }
               }

            });
    });


    /********end of form validation *********/
    </script>
    <div class="page-inner">

        <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <%= message %>
            </div>
            <% } %>

                 <div id="main-wrapper">
                 <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg " href="javascript: history.go(-1)">←Back To previous page</a>
                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                  <div class="col-sm-8 add-plan-form">
                    <div class="row m-t-md">
                        <h1 class="add-plan-heading">Add Content</h1>







    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#myTab li:eq(0) a").tab('show');
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bs-example{
            margin: 20px;
        }
        .col-sm-8 {
        width: 96.667%;
    }
    @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
        #myTab li {
                    width: 100%;
                    margin: 5px 0;
    }
    }
    @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 640px){
        #myTab li {
                    width: 50%;
                    margin: 5px 0;
                    padding: 5px;
    }
    }
    @media (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 767px){
        #myTab li {
                    width: 33%;
                    margin: 5px 0;
                    padding: 5px;
    }
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">Home page content</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">Trainer content</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionc">Home page bottom content</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectiond">Trainers</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectione">Add training type</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionf">Subscription plan content</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectiong">Add Banner</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content clearfix">
            <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <form action="/updateContent?id=<%= editContent.id %>" method="POST" id="planAdd">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Content Heading</label>
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="content_heading" value="<%= editContent.content_heading %>">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Content Description</label>

                                <textarea rows="7" cols="50" name="content_desc" class="form-control" ><%= editContent.content_desc %>


                                </textarea>
                                <span class="Phon_err"></span>
                            </div>


                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Save</button>

                        </form>
            </div> 
            <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
                <form action="/updatetrainContent?id=<%= editcontent2.id %>" method="POST" id="categoryAdd">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Heading</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="heading" value="<%= editcontent2.heading %>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Description</label>
                                <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" name="desc"> -->
                                <textarea rows="7" cols="50" name="desc" class="form-control" ><%= editcontent2.desc %>


                                </textarea>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Save</button>

                        </form>
            </div>
            <div id="sectionc" class="tab-pane fade">
                <form action="/add_img?id=<%= editcontent3.id %>" method="post" id="videoAdd" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Heading</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<%= editcontent3.title %>" >
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group img-d">
                                <label > Thumbnail</label>
                                <div "><input type="file" class="" id="e_Img_file" name=" home_img"></div>
                                <img src="./uploads/homepageimage/<%= editcontent3.home_img %>" height="200" width="220">

                                  <span class="value"></span>
                            </div>


                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right">Save</button>

                        </form>
            </div>
            <div id="sectiond" class="tab-pane fade in active m-div clearfix">
            <h2 class="h-div">
    <a href="/addtrainers" class="">Add new trainer</a></h2>

            <!-- <% if(trainerinfo){  trainerinfo.forEach( function (trainerinf){ %>

        <div class="members animated fadeInLeft visible" data-animation="fadeInLeft" data-animation-delay="300"><div class="content_slider_text_block_wrap"><div class="team-img"><img src="/uploads/trainerprofile/<%- trainerinf.trainer_profile %>" alt="image" class="member_photo" width="250" height="320"></div><div class="team-inner"><div class="team-top center"><h4 class="membername"><%- trainerinf.trainer_name %></h4><br><span class="membername_dec"><%- trainerinf.trainig_type %></span></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="sharemedeia"><a target="_self" href="<%- trainerinf.trainer_facebook %>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a target="_self" href="<%- trainerinf.trainer_twiter %>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a target="_self" href="<%- trainerinf.trainer_google %>"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></div>
    <a href="/edittrainer?id=<%=trainerinf.id; %>">Edit</a>
     <a href="deltrainer?id=<%=trainerinf.id; %>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?');">Delete</a>
    <%   }); }%> -->

    <div class="members_section">
    <div class="row">
    <% if(trainerinfo){  trainerinfo.forEach( function (trainerinf){ %>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 team_m">
            <img src="/uploads/trainerprofile/<%- trainerinf.trainer_profile %>" alt="image" class="member_photo img-responsive">

            <h4 class="membername"><%- trainerinf.trainer_name %><span class="membername_dec">(<%- trainerinf.trainig_type %>)</span></h4>

            <div class="sharemedeia">
                <a target="_self" href="%- trainerinf.trainer_facebook"><span class="s-bg"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span></a>

                <a target="_self" href=""<%- trainerinf.trainer_twiter %>"><span class="s-bg"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span></a>

                <a target="_self" href="<%- trainerinf.trainer_google %>"><span class="s-bg"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span></a></div>

            <div class="ed_de">

            <a href="/edittrainer?id=<%=trainerinf.id; %>">Edit</a>

            <a href="deltrainer?id=<%=trainerinf.id; %>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?');">Delete</a>

            </div>

        </div>  <!--col-sm-4-->
    <%   }); }%>




    </div>  <!--row-->
    </div>  <!--members_section-->  


            </div>
                 <div id="sectione" class="tab-pane fade in active">


    <h2 class="h-div"><a href="/addtrainingtype" >Add new training type</a></h2>





                  <div class="members_section">
    <div class="row">
    <% if(traininginfo){  traininginfo.forEach( function (traininginf){ %>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 team_m">
            <img src="/uploads/trainingtype/<%- traininginf.training_profile %>" alt="image" class="member_photo img-responsive">

            <h4 class="membername"><%- traininginf.trainer_title %></h4>



            <div class="ed_de">

            <a href="/edittraining?id=<%=traininginf.id; %>">Edit</a>

            <a href="deltrainingtype?id=<%=traininginf.id; %>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?');">Delete</a>

            </div>

        </div>  <!--col-sm-4-->
    <%   }); }%>




    </div>  <!--row-->
    </div>  <!--members_section-->       

                    </div>
              <div id="sectionf" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <form action="/subsplanContent?id=<%= plancontents.id %>" method="POST" id="planAdd">

    <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Heading</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<%= plancontents.title %>"  >
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Content Description</label>

                                <textarea rows="7" cols="50" name="content_desc" class="form-control" ><%= plancontents.content_desc %>

                                </textarea>
                                <span class="Phon_err"></span>
                            </div>


                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Save</button>

                        </form>
              </div>
     <div id="sectiong" class="tab-pane fade in active">
     <h2 class="h-div">
    <a href="/addbanner" class="">Add banner image</a></h2>


    <div class="members_section">
    <div class="row">
    <% if(bannerinfo){  bannerinfo.forEach( function (bannerinf){ %>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 team_m">
            <img src="/uploads/bannerimage/<%- bannerinf.banner_image %>" alt="image" class="member_photo img-responsive">





            <div class="ed_de">

            <a href="/edibanner?id=<%=bannerinf.id; %>">Edit</a>

            <a href="deletebanner?id=<%=bannerinf.id; %>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?');">Delete</a>

            </div>

        </div>  <!--col-sm-4-->
    <%   }); }%>




    </div>  <!--row-->
    </div>  <!--members_section-->  

     </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>                            
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: `user: req.user`

Comment: I have replace my code with this still getting same error

Comment: please try to hard code an user object... Is still error ?

Comment: I mean `user: { username : 'blabla', address : 'fdkjsfdsjlfh' }`

Comment: Its not working as if i am passing hard coded  values with in key from controller to view engine.

Comment: I think the problem come from `header.ejs`. Did you print username you somethings like that in your `header` ?. By the way, don't run query like that, if your query is not depen each others. Run query async is more faster...

Comment: I have checked header <%= user.user_name %> its working fine for other controller but not for this controller not getting exact solution.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem?

Comment: No i am getting same issue.

Comment: Can you tell which line has the error?

Comment: I think you should pass unique id to findById function but you are passing a user